# Delete vertical text from empty pages

Tags: titlesec

I already asked this question on this forum, (I would like to put a vertically oriented sentence on all page margins except the table of contents pages), and they gave me a solution that works perfectly but now I would like to put a vertically oriented sentence on all page margins except the table of contents pages and empty pages. this code doesn't delete vertical text from empty pages.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\makeatletter
\newlength\@tempdim@x
\newlength\@tempdim@y
% structure des commandes :
%   #1 = deplacement selon x
%   #2 = deplacement selon y
%   #3 = texte à mettre
\newcommand\AtUpperLeftCorner[3]{%
\begingroup
\@tempdim@x=0cm
\@tempdim@y=\paperheight
\advance\@tempdim@x#1
\advance\@tempdim@y-#2
\put(\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@x},\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@y}){#3}%
\endgroup
}
\newcommand\AtUpperRightCorner[3]{%
\begingroup
\@tempdim@x=\paperwidth
\@tempdim@y=\paperheight
\advance\@tempdim@x-#1
\advance\@tempdim@y-#2
\put(\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@x},\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@y}){#3}%
\endgroup
}
\newcommand\AtLowerLeftCorner[3]{%
\begingroup
\@tempdim@x=0cm
\@tempdim@y=0cm
\advance\@tempdim@x#1
\advance\@tempdim@y#2
\put(\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@x},\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@y}){#3}%
\endgroup
}
\newcommand\AtLowerRightCorner[3]{%
\begingroup
\@tempdim@x=\paperwidth
\@tempdim@y=0cm
\advance\@tempdim@x-#1
\advance\@tempdim@y#2
\put(\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@x},\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@y}){#3}%
\endgroup
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% start edit %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newif\iftoc 

\AddToShipoutPicture{%
    \AtLowerRightCorner{2cm}{5cm}{\ifodd\c@page\iftoc\else \rotatebox{90}{Good \raisebox{0.1ex}{--} My book}\fi\fi}
    \AtLowerLeftCorner{2cm}{5cm}{\ifodd\c@page\else\iftoc\else \rotatebox{90}{Good \raisebox{0.1ex}{--} My book}\fi\fi}
}
\makeatother

\pagenumbering{roman}
\begin{document}
    {\pagestyle{plain}
    \global\toctrue% or place outside braces
    \tableofcontents}

\chapter{Chapter one}\tocfalse
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{one}
\lipsum[2-10]
\section{two}
\lipsum[4]
\section{three}
\lipsum[11]
\chapter{Chapter two}
\section{four}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A start towards your problem --- a revised version of your MWE:

```
% verticaltextprob.tex SE 546962

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\makeatletter
\newlength\@tempdim@x
\newlength\@tempdim@y
% structure des commandes :
%   #1 = deplacement selon x
%   #2 = deplacement selon y
%   #3 = texte à mettre
\newcommand\AtUpperLeftCorner[3]{%
\begingroup
\@tempdim@x=0cm
\@tempdim@y=\paperheight
\advance\@tempdim@x#1
\advance\@tempdim@y-#2
\put(\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@x},\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@y}){#3}%
\endgroup
}
\newcommand\AtUpperRightCorner[3]{%
\begingroup
\@tempdim@x=\paperwidth
\@tempdim@y=\paperheight
\advance\@tempdim@x-#1
\advance\@tempdim@y-#2
\put(\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@x},\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@y}){#3}%
\endgroup
}
\newcommand\AtLowerLeftCorner[3]{%
\begingroup
\@tempdim@x=0cm
\@tempdim@y=0cm
\advance\@tempdim@x#1
\advance\@tempdim@y#2
\put(\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@x},\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@y}){#3}%
\endgroup
}
\newcommand\AtLowerRightCorner[3]{%
\begingroup
\@tempdim@x=\paperwidth
\@tempdim@y=0cm
\advance\@tempdim@x-#1
\advance\@tempdim@y#2
\put(\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@x},\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@y}){#3}%
\endgroup
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% start edit %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newif\iftoc 

\AddToShipoutPicture{%
    \AtLowerRightCorner{2cm}{5cm}{\ifodd\c@page\iftoc\else \rotatebox{90}{Good \raisebox{0.1ex}{--} My book}\fi\fi}
    \AtLowerLeftCorner{2cm}{5cm}{\ifodd\c@page\else\iftoc\else \rotatebox{90}{Good \raisebox{0.1ex}{--} My book}\fi\fi}
}
\makeatother

\pagenumbering{roman}
\begin{document}
    {\pagestyle{plain}
    \global\toctrue% or place outside braces
    \tableofcontents}

\chapter{Chapter one}\tocfalse
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{one}
\lipsum[2-10]
\section{two}
\lipsum[4]
\section{three}
\lipsum[11]
pagetotal = \the\pagetotal % the amount of text on the page
\clearpage
pagetotal = \the\pagetotal
\ifdim\pagetotal=0pt\toctrue\fi % if not text (an empty page) don't print vertical text
\chapter{Chapter two}
\tocfalse % switch vertical text back on
\section{four}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

I used `\pagetotal` to see if a page was empty, if so then set `\toctrue` to prevent printing the vertical text. This works in the MWE. But, how do you decide when to check for an empty page and how do you automatically switch the vertical text back on in the general case?

In your "answer" which is actaully a new question you want it all to be automatic. I have revised, as below, my original MWE which automatically removes the vertical text on empty pages.

```
% verticaltextprob2.tex SE 546962

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\makeatletter
\newlength\@tempdim@x
\newlength\@tempdim@y
% structure des commandes :
%   #1 = deplacement selon x
%   #2 = deplacement selon y
%   #3 = texte à mettre
\newcommand\AtUpperLeftCorner[3]{%
\begingroup
\@tempdim@x=0cm
\@tempdim@y=\paperheight
\advance\@tempdim@x#1
\advance\@tempdim@y-#2
\put(\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@x},\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@y}){#3}%
\endgroup
}
\newcommand\AtUpperRightCorner[3]{%
\begingroup
\@tempdim@x=\paperwidth
\@tempdim@y=\paperheight
\advance\@tempdim@x-#1
\advance\@tempdim@y-#2
\put(\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@x},\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@y}){#3}%
\endgroup
}
\newcommand\AtLowerLeftCorner[3]{%
\begingroup
\@tempdim@x=0cm
\@tempdim@y=0cm
\advance\@tempdim@x#1
\advance\@tempdim@y#2
\put(\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@x},\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@y}){#3}%
\endgroup
}
\newcommand\AtLowerRightCorner[3]{%
\begingroup
\@tempdim@x=\paperwidth
\@tempdim@y=0cm
\advance\@tempdim@x-#1
\advance\@tempdim@y#2
\put(\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@x},\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@y}){#3}%
\endgroup
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% start edit %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newif\iftoc 

\AddToShipoutPicture{%
%  pagetotal = \the\pagetotal
  \ifdim\pagetotal=12.0pt\else    %  new code ---------------------------
    \AtLowerRightCorner{2cm}{5cm}{\ifodd\c@page\iftoc\else \rotatebox{90}{Good \raisebox{0.1ex}{--} My book}\fi\fi}
    \AtLowerLeftCorner{2cm}{5cm}{\ifodd\c@page\else\iftoc\else \rotatebox{90}{Good \raisebox{0.1ex}{--} My book}\fi\fi}
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\pagenumbering{roman}
\begin{document}
    {\pagestyle{plain}
    \global\toctrue% or place outside braces
    \tableofcontents}

\chapter{Chapter one}\tocfalse
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{one}
\lipsum[2-10]
\section{two}
\lipsum[4]
\section{three}
\lipsum[11]
%pagetotal = \the\pagetotal % the amount of text on the page
\clearpage
%pagetotal = \the\pagetotal
%\ifdim\pagetotal=0pt\toctrue\fi % if not text (an empty page) don't print vertical text
\chapter{Chapter two}
%\tocfalse
\section{four}
\lipsum[1]
\cleardoublepage
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

You might have to change the length in the line

```
\ifdim\pagetotal=12.0pt\else
```

to suit your final document (I tried `\baselineskip` instead of the `12.0pt` but that did not work).

Comment: I used the previous code, I insert the commands manually and for the moment everything is fine.
Now I have to try your new code to remove the vertical text automatically. Thank you very much for your answer and your efforts.